# Use field calculation to add string from another field if it is not Null

Tags: python, arcmap

I need to create one column that joins strings from two other columns without creating extra delimeters.

I have one column containing wastewater facility types and another containing water facility types.  Most are Null in one or the other, but some have both water & wastewater facilities.  I want to combine the two columns into one, but I don't want any extra delimiters where null values exist.  The green table in the image is what I am looking for.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfYgv.png)

I am VERY rusty in coding so this is probably very ugly.  I can't figure out how to de-bug it in Arc without just running the calculation.

```html
 Val1 ==  !WATER_TYPE! 
 Val2 == !WASTE_TYPE!
 
 def updateValue(value):
  if Val2 == None:
    return Val1
  else: return !WATER_TYPE! & “, “  & !WASTE_TYPE! 
    
    updateValue(!RAC_TYPES!)
```

Comment: Could you post the code you have tried so far? A good start would be opening the file and looping through each line.

Comment: Just added it to the original question

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
def f(aa, bb=None):  # or bb=''
    if bb:  # this is True if bb exists (i.e., not None)
        return str(aa) + '; ' + str(bb)
    else:
        return str(aa)

f('ADM','LS')  ##Output: 'ADM; LS' 
f('ADM')       ##Output: 'ADM'
```